# Is sex for pleasure (for married brahmins) wrong

Tags: scripture, marriage, brahmins, sex

I have 2 questions

1. For brahmins, is having sex for pleasure (non-procreative purposes) condemned in hindu scriptures? I don't think its mentioned in vedas but non-vedic scriptures are fine.
2. This is less related to hinduism. But I am wondering whether having non-procreative sex after marriage nowadays is normal for brahmins (or other hindus) or if it is only a western cocnept. In western media sex is normalized as if it is just another part of life (eating, drinking, etc) and Ive never discussed such topics with my parents, but I assume that one generation ago and definitely for generations before - people only had sex when trying to have children; this assumption might be wrong.

Comment: There’s a difference between doing things for Indriya tripti vs as necessary karma. Nothing is condemned. It depends on which path you choose.

Comment: Your first question is an interesting one, but I've edited the second part out because it is, though insightful, opinion-based. (Which is off-topic on this site.)

Comment: @CDR don't remove text from OP's question without consent. if you feel opinion based or off-topic, use close votes or ask OP to edit. learn [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/editing) about editing.

Answer (score 2):

Sex for pleasure, in general, is forbidden by scripture, whether it's a Brahmin, whether the person is married or not.

From the Bhagavata Purana, 1.2.9-10:

> Kama in its turn is not a call to indulgence in sexual pleasures, but a mere inducement implanted by the Creator to make life unbroken.

So, yes, as per scripture, it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of Diti and Kashyapa, conjugal relations driven by desire under inauspicious circumstances led to the birth of Hiranyaksha and Hiranyakashipu:

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-bhagavata-purana/d/doc1127062.html

> Diti said:
> 9. “Oh learned, this god of love with a bow in his hand torments me, a poor thing, for your sake just as an elephant attacking a plantain tree crushes it.

> 10. May you be prosperous! Please confer your favour on me who am burning at the (sight of the) prosperity of my co-wives who are blest with children.

....................

> Kaśyapa said:

> 37-38. On account of your impure mind, inauspiciousness of the (evening) time, disobedience to my order and complete disrespect for gods (attending Śiva), Oh evil woman, you will beget two wicked sons the worst ever born from wombs. Oh wrathful woman, they will frequently make the worlds and the protectors of the worlds, cry out (by their atrocious acts).